# scipy.stats.kde and scipy.stats.kstest

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, probability-theory

How can I use `scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde` and `scipy.stats.kstest` in a conformal way?

For example, the code:

```
from numpy import inf
import scipy.stat
my_pdf = scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde(sample)
scipy.stats.kstest(sample, lambda x: my_pdf.integrate_box_1d(-inf, x))
```

Gives the following answer:
`(0.5396735893479544, 0.0)`

Which is not true because a sample obviously belongs to the distribution which was constructed on this sample.

Comment: how did you create your sample? How many observations? It could be that gaussian_kde doesn't match the sample well enough. For example if the sample is bimodal.

Comment: @user333700 Gaussian KDE works just fine for multimodal distributions. When the cdf function is passed properly as in my answer it gets a very low test statistic.

Comment: @Dougal gaussian_kde oversmooths mixture distributions like in the last example here http://jpktd.blogspot.ca/search/label/kernel%20density%20estimation . In this case any goodness of fit test will fail with large enough sample size.

Comment: @user333700 Yes, KDE often oversmooths. Yes, it's the wrong thing to do in this case, as I point out in my answer. But the real problem is almost certainly that *OP is calling it incorrectly*, as I show in my answer, which gets *exaclty* the result he gets. KDE's problems are not going to get you a 0.5 difference between the true and empirical CDFs in a 1d case with more than a handful of samples; that's _insane_.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the right test to use for testing if two samples may have come from the same distribution is the [two-sample KS test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_test), implemented in [`scipy.stats.ks_2samp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html#scipy.stats.ks_2samp), which directly compares the empirical CDFs. KDE is *density* estimation, which smooths out the CDF, and is therefore a bunch of unnecessary work that also makes your estimate worse, statistically speaking.

But the reason you're seeing this problem is that the signature for your CDF parameter isn't quite right. `kstest` calls `cdf(vals)` [(source)](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3414), where `vals` is the sorted samples, to get out the CDF value for each of your samples. In your code, this ends up calling `my_pdf.integrate_box_1d(-np.inf, samps)`, but `integrate_box_1d` wants both arguments to be scalars. The signature is wrong, and if you tried this with most arrays it'd crash with a `ValueError`:

```
>>> my_pdf.integrate_box_1d(-np.inf, samp[:10])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-81d0253a33bf> in <module>()
----> 1 my_pdf.integrate_box_1d(-np.inf, samp[:10])

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.12.0.dev_ddd617d_20120725-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/scipy/stats/kde.pyc in integrate_box_1d(self, low, high)
    311 
    312         normalized_low = ravel((low - self.dataset) / stdev)
--> 313         normalized_high = ravel((high - self.dataset) / stdev)
    314 
    315         value = np.mean(special.ndtr(normalized_high) - \

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10) (1,1000)
```

but unfortunately, when the second argument is `samp`, it can broadcast just fine since the arrays are the same shape, and then everything goes to hell. Presumably `integrate_box_1d` should check the shape of its arguments, but here's one way to do it correctly:

```
>>> my_cdf = lambda ary: np.array([my_pdf.integrate_box_1d(-np.inf, x) for x in ary])
>>> scipy.stats.kstest(sample, my_cdf)
(0.015597917205996903, 0.96809912578616597)
```

You could also use [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) if you felt like it.

(But again, you probably actually want to use `ks_2samp`.)